# Using javascript forEach and splice on multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

I'm trying to loop over some data that look like this:

```
[0]['fields']['status']['name'] = 'In progress'
[1]['fields']['status']['name'] = 'In progress'
[2]['fields']['status']['name'] = 'In review'
[3]['fields']['status']['name'] = 'In progress'
[4]['fields']['status']['name'] = 'In review'
```

I'm using the following foreach loop to splice all useless indexes, in this case all of them.

```
issues.forEach(function (item, index) {
   if (issues[index]['fields']['status']['name'] !== "Done") {
       issues.splice(index, 1);
   }
});
```

If I loop over the array later I can output  'In progress' and 'In review' which is weird because they should be unset. I think this happens because I manipulate the array while using it. Could someone explain what's wrong and how this can be avoided.

Comment: You're splicing while moving *forward*. Splicing will remove an item and then *re-order all following items*. So, if you have array `["a", "b", "c", "d"]` and splice `index = 0` you get rid of `"a"` and you're left with `["b", "c", "d"]`. Next time the callback will be called with `index = 1` so you remove *the wrong item*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just loop from the end with an index.

This prevents unseen indices and keeps the index where it belongs to.

```
var index = issues.length;

while (index--) {
    if (issues[index].fields.status.name !== "Done") {
        issues.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution is replacing *forEach* method with a `while` loop because when you're using `splice`, this will modify the `issues` array `inplace` and you *skip* some elements.

I demonstrated this in the following example.

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4]
arr.forEach((item, index) => {
  arr.splice(index, 1);
});
console.log(arr);
```

Solution

```
let i = 0;
while(i < issues.length){
   if (issues[i]['fields']['status']['name'] !== "Done") {
       issues.splice(i, 1);
   }
   else i++;
}
```