# How to destroy Sprite in PixiJS from array properly?

Tags: javascript, typescript, canvas, pixi.js

I have a list of components which has private sprite property and render/destroy methods.

```
export default class BlockScene implements IBaseComponent {
    public props: IBlock;
    private readonly image: HTMLImageElement;
    private sprite: Sprite;
    private app: Application;
    private readonly startX: number;
    private readonly startY: number;
    private readonly onClickCallback: (block: BlockScene) => void;

    constructor(block: IBlock,
        app: Application,
        onClickCallBack: (block: BlockScene) => void) {
        this.image = new Image(BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE);
        this.image.src = blocksMap[block.color];
        this.props = block;
        this.app = app;
        this.onClickCallback = onClickCallBack;
        this.startY = (this.app.renderer.height / 2) - FIELD_SIZE / 2 + FIELD_PADDING - BLOCK_SIZE;
        this.startX = (this.app.renderer.width / 2) - FIELD_SIZE / 2 + FIELD_PADDING - BLOCK_SIZE;
    }

    public destroy() {
        this.sprite.destroy();
    }

    public async reRender() {
        this.destroy();
        await this.render();
    }

    public async render() {
        const texture = await Assets.load(this.image.src);
        this.sprite = new Sprite(texture);
        this.sprite.x = this.startX + (this.props.position.x * BLOCK_SIZE);
        this.sprite.y = this.startY + (this.props.position.y * BLOCK_SIZE);
        if (!this.props.empty) {
            this.sprite.eventMode = 'static';
            this.sprite.cursor = 'pointer';
            this.sprite.on('click', this.onClick, this);
            this.sprite.on('pointerover', this.onPointerOver, this);
            this.sprite.on('pointerleave', this.onPointerLeave, this);
            this.sprite.on('mousedown', this.onMouseDown, this);
            this.sprite.on('mouseup', this.onMouseUp, this);
        }
        if (this.props.empty) {
            this.sprite.width = 0;
            this.sprite.height = 0;
        } else {
            this.sprite.width = BLOCK_SIZE;
            this.sprite.height = BLOCK_SIZE;
        }
        if (this.props.superBoost) {
            this.sprite.tint = 0x6b6b6b;
        }
        this.app.stage.addChild(this.sprite);
    }

    private async onClick() {
        await this.onClickCallback(this);
    }

    private onMouseDown() {
        this.sprite.alpha = 0.5;
    }

    private onMouseUp() {
        this.sprite.alpha = 0.8;
    }

    private onPointerOver() {
        this.sprite.alpha = 0.8;
    }

    private onPointerLeave() {
        this.sprite.alpha = 1;
    }
}
```

And I have a method for rendering list of sprites

```
    private async renderBlocks() {
        return Promise.all(
            this.state.blocks.map(async (block) => {
                const component = new BlockScene(
                    block,
                    this.app,
                    this.onBlockClick.bind(this));
                await component.render();
                this.blocks.push(component);
                return block;
            })
        );
    }
```

Whole component responsible for rendering of list

```
export default class FieldScene implements IBaseComponent {
    private readonly app: Application;
    private sprite: Sprite;
    private state: GameModel;
    private readonly startX: number;
    private readonly startY: number;
    private blocks: BlockScene[] = [];

    constructor(app: Application, state: GameModel) {
        this.app = app;
        this.state = state;
        this.startY = (this.app.renderer.height / 2) - FIELD_SIZE / 2 + FIELD_PADDING - BLOCK_SIZE;
        this.startX = (this.app.renderer.width / 2) - FIELD_SIZE / 2 + FIELD_PADDING - BLOCK_SIZE;
    }

    private async reGenerateField(afterMix = false) {
        if (!afterMix) {
            gameModel.generateBlocks();
        }
        await this.reRender();
    }

    private reRenderAllTheDisplays() {
        pointsDisplayScene.reRender();
        turnsDisplayScene.reRender();
        mixesDisplayScene.reRender();
    }

    private removeBlocks(blocksList: IBlock[]) {
        blocksList.forEach((removeBlock) => {
            const found = this.blocks.find((block) => {
                return comparePosition(block.props.position, removeBlock.position);
            });
            if (found) {
                found.destroy();
            }
        });
    }

    public async onBlockClick(block: BlockScene) {
        try {
            const res = gameModel.onBlockClick(block.props);
            this.removeBlocks(res.stages.remove.removeBlocks);
            await delay(1000);
            const {gameStatus} = res;
            if (gameStatus === 'mix') {
                await this.reGenerateField(true);
                mixesDisplayScene.reRender();
                gameResultScene.render(gameStatus);
                return;
            }
            if (gameStatus === 'loss' || gameStatus === 'win') {
                gameResultScene.render(gameStatus);
                await this.reGenerateField();
                return;
            }
            await this.reRender();
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
        } finally {
            this.reRenderAllTheDisplays();
        }
    }

    public destroy() {
        this.blocks.forEach((b) => b.destroy());
        this.blocks = [];
    }

    public async reRender() {
        this.destroy();
        await this.renderBlocks();
    }

    private async renderBlocks() {
        return Promise.all(
            this.state.blocks.map(async (block) => {
                const component = new BlockScene(
                    block,
                    this.app,
                    this.onBlockClick.bind(this));
                await component.render();
                this.blocks.push(component);
                return block;
            })
        );
    }

    public async render() {
        const image = new Image(FIELD_SIZE, FIELD_SIZE);
        image.src = FieldImage;
        const texture = await Assets.load(image.src);
        this.sprite = new Sprite(texture);
        this.sprite.width = FIELD_SIZE;
        this.sprite.height = FIELD_SIZE;

        this.sprite.x = this.app.renderer.width / 2;
        this.sprite.y = this.app.renderer.height / 2;
        this.sprite.anchor.x = 0.5;
        this.sprite.anchor.y = 0.5;
        this.app.stage.addChild(this.sprite);

        await this.renderBlocks();
    }
}
```

And I try to remove (destroy) some sprites outside the component using public method **destroy()**

The code for destroying

```
private removeBlocks(blocksList: IBlock[]) {
        blocksList.forEach((removeBlock) => {
            const found = this.blocks.find((block) => {
                return comparePosition(block.props.position, removeBlock.position);
            });
            if (found) {
                found.destroy();
            }
        });
    }
```

But this code deletes sometimes the other sprites which don't match the condition. What is the problem? I can't understand how to catch the error.

I tried to change removeBlocks() method but it doesn't work

Comment: Can you try to iterate the array backwards? You might be skipping indices https://stackoverflow.com/a/59931874/2886688

Comment: I don't see the code for `comparePosition`? The error may be in the comparison?
Another problem is that your code contains a LOT of `async await`, which may cause unexpected results when you loop over all blocks while some blocks are still awaiting.